# Find $L(-3t-3)$ by using the definition of $L$ and the matrices obtained in parts 1. and 2.

Tags: matrices

The original question is as follows: Let $P_1\to P_2$ (vector space of polynomials degree 1 mapped to vector space of polynomials degree 2) be defined by $L(p(t))=t(p(t))+p(0)$. Consider the ordered basis $S=\{t, 1\}$ and $S'=\{t+1, t-1\}$ for $P_1$, and $T=\{t^2, t, 1\}$ and $T'=\{t^2+1, t-1, t+1\}$ for $P_2$. Find the representation of $L$ with respect to:

1. $S$ and $T$: I got this one - Solution is the following 3x2 matrix
   $$\left(\begin{matrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 \\
      0 & 1
      \end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{This is correct.}$$
2. $S'$ and $T'$: Again, this one is the following 3x2 matrix
   $$\left(\begin{matrix}
      1 & 1 \\
      1/2 & 1/2 \\
      1/3 & -3/2
      \end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{This is also correct.}$$
3. This is the one I'm have an issue with. It asks: Find $L(-3t-3)$ by using the definition of $L$ and the matrices obtained in parts 1. and 2.

I not sure if I understand what I'm being asked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, your matrices for S and T should be different. S and T have different dimensions so the matrices should be different.  For part 3, factor out the -3 to get -3*L(t+1). You can evaluate     L(t+1) assuming your matrix for S' is corret

Comment: Ignore the first part of my previous comment.  I still think your S and T matrix is incorrect. For instance, t is sent to t^2 and 1 is sent to 2t. Thus, the first column should be (1,2,0). This is all I checked. There may be more mistakes

Comment: I double checked and it's right.
$L(t) = t(t)+(0) = t^2+0$
$L(t) = t(1)+(1) = t+1$

That gives the result for part 1:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 1
   \end{matrix}\right)\quad\text{This is correct.}$$

I know it has something to do with matrix multiplication but somehow I'm just not certain what to multiply exactly. The question hints at using the previous matrices from parts 1 and 2 but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I made another mistake in my comment about the first column being (1,2,0). what you have-(1,0,0) is right. But the second column needs to be (0,2,0) since L(1)=2t, and 2t has the representation (0,2,0) in the basis T

Comment: And as I mentioned in my first comment, once you have your matrices correct, you must realize that L(-3t-3)=-3*L(t+1).  Using your matrix of S' to T', you can evaluate L(t+1)-it will be your first column. Then multiply it by -3

Answer (score 0):

I should give an official answer to this question.

Make sure your matrices correct as mentioned earlier. Then you must realize that $L(-3t-3)=-3L(t+1)$. Using your matrix of $S'$ to $T'$, you can evaluate $L(t+1)$-it will be one of your columns. Then multiply that by $-3$ to get your answer in terms of $T'$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe you're correct about the solution. It seems that the solution manual is wrong. The solutions answer is $-3t^2+3t+3$ which, to me, doesn't make complete sense. There are a couple of us trying to wrap our heads around the answer. Thanks!